How to make points sit on the plane?
I did some geometry nodes using the donut tutorial as guide. I want my points (dog food) to sit on the plane, not to be within it. Any ideea how? Please help! If you look closely, theres my model dog food which stays on top.



At the top right of your screen, there is an "options" menu

Click that menu and enable "affect only origins"


Select the original food (the one you modeled outside the geometry nodes)
Grab it (in object mode)

You will notice that only the origin is moving, not the food (yes!)
Move the origin to the bottom of the food



Make sure the rotations in the nodes don't include X and Y, only Z
Remember to uncheck the "affect only origins"

Thank you so much!!!!

@busuiocar, if this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)
